# Java code for Bitcoin Mining?

Tags: java, mining-software

I am a student and doing research on Bitcoin. I wanted to know how mining is done but I wanted it see the some basic java code. Can some one provide me with resources? I would appreciate if some one can suggest me some libraries to look into. I checked BitcoinJ but found out that it does not support mining.

Thanks

Comment: There are several mining clients written in Java. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_software Does one of those answer your question?

Comment: @coder121: does it need to be a Java library? Which platform are you running it on? Android, per chance?

Comment: @WizardOfOzzie It should be Java. I am not running on any mobile device. I wanted to run it on my pc.

Answer (score 4):

One of the very fist GPU miners was in java using OpenCL.  It was called DiabloMiner and you can find the source here;-

https://github.com/Diablo-D3/DiabloMiner

It hasn't been updated the the past two years but it is still fully functional.

Comment: Will surely look into this.

Comment: 2019- Does not support the current protocol

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any Java mining code existing, and I would not expect it to: mining needs to be as fast as possible, so you wouldn't want to write it in a language that runs on a virtual machine.

Since the reference implementation, Bitcoin Core, stands as the ultimate  documentation of the protocol, and it is written in C++, I would say that anyone doing research on Bitcoin needs at least a competent reading knowledge of C++. Once you have that, you can read the mining code in Bitcoin Core.

Comment: Thanks Nate. But I am not competent in C++ .Hence I am looking for something in Java.

Comment: @Coder121: My point is that I think your best bet to reaching a full understanding of this process is to *learn* enough C++ to read the existing code.  I don't think it will be a tremendous leap if you already know Java.

Answer (score -1):

Mining BITCOIN..
It's so easy..no matter what..Are you shocked are thrilled..?

Yes it's true.
Mining is searching for a packet of a particular algorithm etc.,
Where will it search ?
Internet..and it comes from a source.
So who ever create these source our mining should run on those source.
The more miners from these all providers the more verification process happens..the more valid means more closer to solve a block..
So we want miners from all around the world connecting to all internet providers of this world mining under one domain..we can also call it a pool..

So development should be needed in that piece of code which allows to search for that particular algorithm. Using a simple PC with High speed internet..

All the very best..
If logic clicks .. anything is possible..here especially..lol